# WebSocket - failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could anybody help me find the solution for the problem I'm trying to solve, it's really annoying and delays are horrible I'm running application with NodeJS and Socket.io I tried to find a solution on my own but I couldn't find anything for this type of problem.

It works fine on localhost but when I upload the code on the server this error appears.

[Screenshoot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adwdu.png)

Here is server code:

```
//Socket config
var http = require('http');
//var server = http.createServer(app);
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    
    socket.on('test', function(data) {
        console.log(data.name);
    
    }); 
});
server.listen(443);
```

Here is client code:

```
<script src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('https://www.example.com/');
    socket.emit('test', {name: "John"});
</script>
```

Note: this isn't the actual code it's just an example even if i had this same code I would still get the error.

Comment: Please provide the code which is causing the problem.

Comment: This may not be related to your problem, but is your server running on HTTP or HTTPS? Currently it looks like you are listening on a HTTPS port with HTTP.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes I have my site on public domain it has ssl so its https and the port is https (443).